# Sprite Renderers and UI images scaling

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am trying to match the size of a grid in Unity UI Canvas with another grid which consists of sprite renderers.

[The UI Cell Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Eon.png)

[The Sprite Renderer Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW5AZ.png)

What I would like to do is to set the UI Grid on top of the Sprite Renderer grid.
I was able to achieve this in 9:16(with my canvas scaler set at 1600-900 with 0.5 width/height match) aspect ratio with setting the UI Grid and Sprite Renderer's parent position as Vector3.zero.

However, when I change to a different aspect ratio (say 9:18) I change my Canvas Scaler in the UI Grid's canvas to 1800-900 with 0.5 width and height match for other UI purposes.
After which the 2 grids dont align anymore. (Even with their position vectors set to zero).
I understand there's a difference in where it is being rendered, so is there anyway I can scale my Sprite Renderer grid with respect to the UI grid?

Also, I am using 2 cameras to render the UI canvas and sprite renderer grid separately. Im assuming I have to change the orthographic size of the camera rendering the sprite renderer grid? But what is the calculation behind it?